# ¿Cómo puedo invocar un Windows Form desde una clase.cs?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo una clase llamada servicioTest que necesita invocar el formulario (frmTest). Ya intenté haciendo una instancia del formulario, pero me indica que no lo logra encontrar.

Clase servicioTest:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CapaConexion
{
    class ServicioTest
    {
        frmTest instancia = new frmTest();
        instancia.show();
    }
}
```

Y el Windows Form (frmTest):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CapaPresentacion
{
    public partial class frmTest : Form
    {
        public frmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

El error que me dice es:
[image: Este es el error que me dice]

Y las capas sobre las que está son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota: La clase servicioTest se encuentra en la capa llamada CapaConexion y el frmTest en una llamada CapaPresentacion. **

Las referencias que tengo en mi capa presentación son:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el error que lanza es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta crear una clase ServicioTest limpia y crea una instancia del formulario en el constructor, creo que te presentará el mismo problema. Si es así, muestranos el error. Por favor, intenta reducir al máximo tu problema y presentar un código reproducible para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Revisa la sección [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: pon using CapaPresentacion en en los usings de la clase Servicio

Comment: @Carlos Hice lo que me indicas, al crear la instancia el error que me da es: "El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres "frmProfesor" no se encontró(¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de emsamblado?)". Te indico que despues de añadir la referencia y utilizar el using para añadir el formulario, sigue sucediendo el mismo problema.

Comment: @Japv ¡Ya lo intenté y no funciona!

Comment: @KobeMoya Modifica tu pregunta para que solo muestres eso (la clase simple y el error) y no tengas tantas cosas innecesarias que nada tienen que ve con el error, y agrega una imagen de tus referencias.

Comment: @Carlos, disculpa los inconvenientes, soy nuevo en esto de stackoverflow, ya he hecho lo que me pedías. :D

Comment: Cada capa es un proyecto, por lo  tanto, para que pueda  ver la CapaPresentación le tienes que  agregar al   Proyecto CapaConexion una referencia al  proyecto CapaPresentacion. Una vez que agregues  la referencia  entonces podrán agregar el using.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich intenté hacer eso, pero CapaPresentación no me genera nigún archivo .dll

Comment: Has la referencia  al proyecto no a DLL. Al añadir  referencias tienes la opción de  hacerlo a  los  proyectos  de tu solución.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Como puedo hacerlo? La unica opción sería que añada la carpeta completa del proyecto.

Comment: @KobeMoya Dale click derecho al proyecto CapaConexion y dale Agregar>Referencia. Selecciona CapaPresentacion y dale Ok. Finalmente agrega el using CapaPresentacion en los using

Comment: Aquí hay información de cómo agregar referencias: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019. La Pestaña Proyectos es la que debes de ver en la u caso

Comment: @Carlos al añadir la referencia de CapaPresentacion me añade TODOS los archivos que tiene CapaPresentacion, incluso sucede un error al hacerlo.

Comment: @KobeMoya Agrega esto que comentas a tu pregunta con capturas de los errores. Además, agrega captura del nodo Referencias extendido (en la que agregaste no está extendido el nodo y no se ven las referencias)

Comment: @Carlos ya he actualizado la pregunta. Dime si hace falta algo.

Comment: @KobeMoya En tu CapaConexion no tienes referecnia a CapaPresentacion. Realiza lo que te mencioné y añade los demás errores que dices que te sucede. Así como que te añade TODOS los archivos.

Comment: @Carlos Ya lo he resuelto. Lo que estaba pasando es que se importaban todos los archivos porque estaba implementando toda la carpeta de CapaPresentación. Entonces cambié la referenci a la capa, no a la carpeta como tal.  ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda!